# HIde a Column in Repeater Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

How do I hide a particular column in Asp Repeater ? I want to hide POwner in this case !

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%#Eval("Priority") %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%#Eval("ProjectName") %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("POwner") %>'></asp:Label>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Adding this in code behind gives an error :s

```
public void Repeater1_ItemDatabound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater a =(Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
    a.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: it is inside a repeater control

Comment: then why are you casting to a `Repeater` ?! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label1` is a `Label` control and not `Repeater`, that's why you're getting an error

You also need to add an `if` condition so you only get the `Label1` for items and not for header or footer.

Try with this

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    Label label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
    label.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this is the error I get !

Comment: @user1373852: just to confirm, are you still getting the same error after changing the code?

Comment: Yes  Label label =(Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
            label.Visible = false;

Comment: @user1373852: all repeater rows are bound, included header and footer. That's why they are there.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast Label1 to a Label not to a repeater try this :

```
Label a =(Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
a.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

i suppose it's impossible. but i can be mistaken

maybe you can try to use following inside your item template:

```
<tr>
<td runat="server" visible='<%# expression %'>
......
</td>
<td>
....
</tr>
```

or use ListView control instead Repeater